# Executing maven goal for active module in IntelliJ

Tags: maven, intellij-idea

I have a multi-module project in IntelliJ and I am trying to execute a maven goal on "the active module".

In Eclipse, mapping Maven->Install to a shortcut key would automatically detect the active module and execute the goal for it.

I'm aware that you can map a shortcut key to a specific goal for a specific module, but I have not seen a feature to execute a goal against the active module. Does this concept exist in IntelliJ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Maven Helper](http://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7179?pr=idea_ce) contains such feature - you can run/debug maven goals for a module that contains the current file. You can also setup shortcuts for your goals.

Comment: Perfect. That's exactly what I was looking for.